# How to deal with long variable names when using stargazer to make tables in R?

Tags: r, stargazer

I try to display the first 20 rows of a data frame by using stargazer. But some of the variable names are so long (such as `Prevelance of unnourishment (% of population)`) that the table just cannot fit in. I understand that renaming the variables with shorter names will work but that's not the way I'm looking for. I also thought about changing the latex codes that has been produced but turned out those cannot be changed. I guess the best way is to do something with the R command. Mine is:

```
stargazer(as.matrix(data[1:20,]), type='latex')
```

How should I change it to make the table fit in? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `abbreviate` to shorten names. You can control the length of names by adjusting `minlength` argument. For more info, please read `?abbreviate`

By following this, sometimes non-unique names may appear, so to take care of it, you would use `make.unique` on the abbreviated names.

```
colnames(data) <- abbreviate( colnames(data), minlength = 3, strict = TRUE )
stargazer(as.matrix(data[1:20,]), type='latex')
```